# MHD plasma regime clarification

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

Could you give an intuition about why does MHD requires the following condition in time and spatial scales, please? Thanks.

*At scales much larger than the mean free path and gyroradius, and time scales much larger
than the collision time and gyroperiod, the magnetohydrodynamics (MHD) model is good.*

Comment: If you take out the gyroradius & gyroperiod, would you agree that the statement holds for a fluid description?

Comment: If you allow for gyro motion of different species of particles, the best approximation you can get away with is a multi-fluid plasma (strictly speaking, MHD is usually treated as a single fluid when people say "MHD plasma"... otherwise they will specify it is a multi-species magnetized fluid).